# Indentation for internal styling

Tags: css

I am a little confused as to which is the correct syntax to use for the following so does the styled element need indenting? According to the docs at w3schools the unindented version would seem correct but i have been told conflicting answers on this.

```
<style>
h2 {color:red;}
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
  h2 {color:red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both indentions are correct, there is no wrong or right here.

The second approach would be more readable, however.

I would even write this as:

```
<style>
  h2 {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

There is a nice article by Louis Lazaris in Smashing Magazine on [Using White Space For Readability In HTML And CSS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/using-white-space-for-readability-in-html-and-css/). You might want to read it. But as of your question, there is no actual restiction on code indention in the CSS specification.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. Second one is structured for readable. I would use second one just to keep my code consistent... To know How to structure css as a beginner visit this link.

> http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/applyingcss/